# Revoke read access to Sitecore page returns "Document not found"

Tags: security

I installed a vanilla Sitecore instance and revoked read access to the home page and published it. When I accessed the page I got "document not found" instead of access denied.

Comment: Could you provide the steps that you've done for restricting the read access for home page. And which version of Sitecore do you use?

Comment: I am using 8.2.5 and the steps were done correctly but Sitecore said that it's a bug

Comment: According to Sitecore, the source of the issue is
"ItemResolver doesn't change HttpRequestArgs.PermissionDenied when it is needed"
The resolution includes a dll and a config file.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Sitecore on that and they said that it's a bug and provided my with a patch to fix it 
 reference number 183497

Comment: do you still have this patch?